# How long does mongodb wait for new data when opening a tailable cursor

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

After opening a tailable cursor `(AwaitData | NoCursorTimeout | TailableCursor)`, calling `MoveNext()` on blocks for a very short interval (it seems less that 1000ms).  The purpose of `AwaitData` is to tell the server to wait a while for new data if it has reached the end of data, which it seems to be doing, but can that wait time be configured or is there documentation on how long it currently waits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not configurable. The wait time is anywhere between 2 and 2.3 seconds.

You are not the only one who finds it to be a peculiar design decision.

Comment: The cursor still returns results when new documents are inserted if you call `MoveNext()` or your driver's equivalent function repeatedly though.